# Can't add bounty to question

Tags: support, stack-overflow, bounties

On Stack Overflow, there's no button on my post to say 'add bounty.' It's been +2 days since I posted and also there's a button now that says'  'question eligible for bounty since 22 hours ago' but it links me to the 'what is a bounty' page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to place a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51642992/4751173). Since you have posted an answer there, the minimum bounty is **100**, not 50, so it's not possible for you right now to place a bounty.

Comment: Thanks for that. The answer I posted didn't actually work for me. Would it work if I'd delete my answer then could I set a bounty for 50 rep?

Comment: Alas, that doesn't work. People have asked before to fix that, but to no avail.

Comment: Ah well, I'll just wait for an answer. Thank you :)